# MathJax conflict with NoScript

Tags: support, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tex broken for me…](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/597/tex-broken-for-me)

Hi all,

I have been using NoScript on Firefox. Even though I allow all the Javascripts in math.SE page to load, all the equations cannot be rendered (Math Processing error). The bottom left corner also shows that the javascript files failed to load. There's no problem with the site when I use Chrome though.

p.s. I have no problem with MO though.

Question: How can I configure NoScript so that math.SE would work in firefox?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/597/tex-broken-for-me/601#601?